# Noob looking for log out

Tags: discussion

Sorry for such a noob question, but where is the log out?

I have looked under every menu option. Can not find it in the title bar.

Typed in search box looking for results or instructions, not listed on the help page.

Checked the footer. Am I suppose to stay logged on forever?

Comment: Well this question have nothing to do here but it's on the StackExchange logo (left of your header). You can click on it and just log out.

Comment: We have a place for asking about SO--[meta]

Comment: And the link should also be on a user's profile.  It is kinda hidden.

Comment: Alright already, why the lock on accepting an answer. Got to wait 10 minutes?? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: I disagree that it has nothing to do here, it is directly related to the use of the site. But I do appreciate the focus of the site was not specifically on its own functionality and use, yet that should be described somewhere. It was not even included in the 2 minute tour!!! Down vote is not justified in this case.

Comment: Ah nice that this got moved!! sorry for the above comment. didn't know there was a support site for the site.

Comment: @Rishabh, still have to wait 5 more minutes before I can accept your answer sorry!!!

Comment: Yes, you have to wait - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47814/248731

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click on StackExchange icon, you'll find it.

Comment: This answer needs better explanation. It's not clear to a newcomer what “the StackExchange icon” is or where it is.

Answer (score 8):

It's hidden under the StackExchange dropdown menu at the top left.

[image: Log Out]

Comment: Plus 1 when I am finally allowed for the graphic!!!

Comment: Plus 1 for freehand circle: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/66838#66838

Answer (score 2):

Click on the StackExchange banner up in the nav bar (far left), on the very right of the popup menu you'll find the logout link.

Comment: thanks, got it from an earlier post.